# adding a route table entry in switch hub or something

Tags: networking, route

It is widely known that a network packet can be sent forcely to a designated port(a physical port in switch hub device) by adding a route table entry. For example,

(In Windows Console in host A)
c:>route add B mask 255.255.255.255 X
Enforces any packet from A to B to go to the host X.

However, I recently found that it cannot be done unless host A allows adding a route table entry.

I don't know about L3 switch devices, however, I just guess it may be resolved by adding an route table entry in L3 switch device configuration, but I am not sure.

Is there any way to add that route table entry not in host A, but in other way?

Please reply. Thanks in advance.

Hyun-jik Bae

Answer (score -1):

Routing table entries tell your local computer which one of its interfaces to use when trying to send data to a given address. You cannot use it to tell the machine to send packets intended for one address to another address.